# Emergency stop when the glossaries package is loaded together with other packages

Tags: errors, glossaries

The following document compiles well.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\maketitle
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

However, the compilation of the very similar following document fails with an error.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,glossaries,latexsym}
\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\maketitle
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The error produced is

> Emergency stop.

Why?

Comment: The second version runs for me without problems, but `glossaries` should not be loaded in a `\usepackage{...}` list of packages. (which I never recommend anyway).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, you're right. I closed the document, reopened it and recompiled, and now it works well. I don't understand it, but the important thing is it works. Thanks!

Comment: The second version runs fine, even after having just run the first one.  May be you had some auxiliary file around that corrected on a subsequent run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX's error message is never `Emergency stop` or at least that is never the main, or even most important, part of the message.

TeX does an emergency stop when an error condition occurs that requires user input, but it is running in `\batchmode` or is otherwise prevented from having interactive input, so it stops.

For example if I add

```
\batchmode
\immediate\openout5 ../zzzz
```

to any file, this will by default be an error as the default security settings prevent writing to a parent directory.

I get in the log:

```
! I can't write on file `../zzzz.tex'.
l.2 \immediate\openout5 ../zzzz

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name
! Emergency stop.
l.2 \immediate\openout5 ../zzzz

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

The first 5 lines are the usual "interactive" error dialog but then rather than wait for the user to input the requested filename, as it is running in `\batchmode` it issues an emergency stop message and stops. so you see `Emergency stop` line, then after that it tells you why it stopped (`file error in nonstop mode`).